# Changes in RobotNavigator.cpp have no effect

Tags: ros, nav2d-exploration, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am seeing a strange effect that even though I removed some comments from RobotNavigator.cpp file in nav2s_navigator package. When I run it, I can still see the same log messages in rqt_console and terminal.

Any idea whats the root cause?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220902/changes-in-robotnavigator.cpp-have-no-effect/) by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

had to just compile the file using catkin_make. Silly Mistake

---

Originally posted by [robo_explorer](https://answers.ros.org/users/24464/robo_explorer/) with karma: 29 on 2015-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-11-13**:
Please use the checkbox at the left to accept your own question. I voted up your question so you have enough karma now